# how to replicate putty ssh tunnel settings with pure command line commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, tunnel, tunneling

After a day of searching I am unable to replicate the feature with command line for ssh tunnel and reverse tunnel.

reverse ssh tunnel configuration
[image: reverse ssh tunnel configuration to the SSH server]
normal ssh tunnel configuration
[image]

**with the UI settings above I am able to get it working with instruction on the web!**

currently I am trying to do

device 1 connect to (ssh server) and passes its port 80 to port 9191 onto the server then the server relays the port 9191 to device #3.

(device #1 reverse tunnel port 9191 to server device #2) <--> (server device #2 receives port 80 and use it as port 9191 which will relay to device #3) <--> (device #3 with normal tunnel to get port 9191 from device #1 with device #2 being the middle man)

I am able to use the putty user interface to click do get it working, but I am unable to replicate a working situation with command line.   ssh command line examples out there do not seem to work.

for example:
on reverse tunnel device

**ssh -R 9191:localhost:80 root@localhost**

on the normal tunnel device

**ssh -L 9191:localhost:9191 root@localhost**

please let me know if the question is lacking info or unclear
thanks!

To clarify my intent,  I am trying to make a tunnel between (2 android devices) with a SSH server.   I can't SSH directly into an android mobile device simply because of firewall issue, so I have to  use a standalone SSH server to act as a middleman to help relay the connection.   However if there is any other better options please let me know as well, for example VPN or anything which may not use a lot of battery power on our mobile devices through 3g/wifi.

any other options would be fine but please consider 3g/wifi/firewall/battery consumption/data overhead concerns as well.  I am not sure how does the major mobile app handle this, so any new ideas or methods are welcomed.

thanks in advanced

Comment: What doesn't work? You don't say what is the actual problem with using the commandline

Comment: basically after initialize those basic commands, the tunnel does not seem to be established in the same way its done like from the GUI.   so basically if i am on 2nd device or 3rd device, it 's unable to see port 9191 from device#1.

Comment: I don't understand your "(device) <--> (server) <--> (device)" diagram. Which computer are you on? Which computer do you want to SSH to? Which computer do you want the tunnel to connect to?

Comment: Basically  reverse tunnel on device#1   share with device #3.   But device #2 the server is just the middleman acting as the ssh server plus help passing through the tunnel data.

Comment: So, `ssh` is being invoked on server 1, connecting to server2? Do you want a tunnel from 1 to 3 or from 2 to 1?

Comment: device 1 connect to (ssh server) and passes its port 80 to port 9191 onto the server then the server relays the port 9191 to device #3.   To clarify my intent,  I am trying to make a tunnel between (2 android devices) with a SSH server.   I can't SSH directly into an android mobile device simply because of firewall issue, so I have to  use a standalone SSH server to act as a middleman to help relay the connection.   However if there is any other better options please let me know as well, for example VPN or anything which may not use a lot of battery power on our mobile devices through 3g/wifi.

Comment: from #1 to #3,    but #2 is the middleman SSH server

Answer (score 2):

As i understand from the comments, you're on Device 1 (Android A), trying to talk to Device 3 (Android B) via Device 2 (SSH host).

Try this on Android A:

```
ssh -L 9191:android_b:9191 root@ssh_host
```

On Android B:

```
ssh -L 9191:android_a:80 root@ssh_host
```

Or also from Android A:

```
ssh -R 9191:android_a:80 root@ssh_host
```

That should serve Android A's port 80 on Android B's port 9191, and that one on Android A's port 9191.

Answer (score 0):

On Device A

```
ssh -R 9191:127.0.0.1:80 user@RemoteHost
```

On Device B

```
ssh -L 9191:127.0.0.1:9191 user@RemoteHost
```